# <bean:message key='keyvalue'> does not work in js file while work perfectly in jsp file

Tags: javascript, jsp, application-resource

does not work in js file while it works perfectly in jsp file. I need to display alerts in font other than english for which i am making use of the applicationResource.properties file. It is working perfectly in jsp file but does not work with js file. Is there any solution for the same.Please help.! ! ! ! !

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I'm curious to find out if you can pass bean values into JavaScript in an external js file. I've typically only done it within <script></script> on the jsp.

Comment: Hey hii Greg..I got it thanks..
I found one work around solution for the same. I am passing the bean message inside one global variable inside jsp file and then passing that variable inside alert in JS file. it works...

Comment: If you have found solution. Then post answer here and mark it accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare any global variable in jsp file and pass your bean message key inside that.
And then pass this value in alert box inside JS file.